# How to efficiently render different nav bar using Vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

So I'm creating a relatively large website using Vue and Vue-router and different pages require different navigation bars (each custom components rendered on top of the page)(and some pages don't have a navbar at all) and currently I'm using a similar format to this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="firstNavbar">
            <FirstNav />
        <div>
        <div v-if="secondNavbar">
            <SecondNav />
        </div>
       <router-view />
    </div>
</template>
```

But re-rendering the entire page for every routing event just because the navbar changed seems a bit inefficient, and I was wondering what I could do to remedy this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: A v-if SHOULD NOT cause your entire page to re-render... Why are you using a routing event to change a single component in the first place? Do you need history or something?

Comment: @BryceHowitson I just need different navbars for different pages but for a lot of the pages, it's the same navbar, and I honestly believe there's a more efficient way than having the same component being rerendered at the same position with the same exact data across different pages.

Comment: Yeah don't put it in the target page put your nav in the app.vue template. Then only the page content is changed not the nav

Comment: @BryceHowitson Right, I mean, I'm already doing that, except what do I do when I want to change the navbar?

Comment: What you're doing looks correct. If that code is in the app.vue router changes ARE NOT re-rendering the nav. Vue only rerenders the content that changes. In this case the stuff inside `router-view`. If you're still worried about performance you could use `v-show` instead of `v-if`. Show keeps the component in the DOM and just changes visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the use of `<keep-alive>` element to cache the navbars. Try this

#### APP.vue

```js
<template>
  <keep-alive>
    <component :is="getConditionallyRenderedNavbar"></component>
  </keep-alive>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
  import firstNavbar from './firstNavbar.vue';
  import secondNavbar from './secondNavbar.vue;
 
  export default{
    components:{
      firstNavbar,
      secondNavbar
    },
    computed: {
       getConditionallyRenderedNavbar() {
         return firstNav //or second nav or no nav
       }
    }
  }

</script>
```

To find out more, check [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

Comment: Thanks this seems to be what I was looking for! If I understood correctly, the best thing to do would to still watch for route changes, and then have a conditional in `getConditionallyRenderedNavbar()`, correct?

Comment: Yeah. That is one way to go. You mentioned that there's a particular navbar used throughout more than the others
you can have 
data() {
  return {
    navbarSelected: 'navbar.....'
  }
}
Your component element will now be 
`<component :is="navbarSelected"></component>`
You won't need the computed property again, in this case.
You can watch for a route change and put a conditional whereby the other routes that use the seldom used navbar will change the value of `this.navbarSelected`.
You can check if there's a more readable way.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, you can select the answer if it satisfies what you want. :)